# <p> tag always under background in <div>

Tags: html, css, background-image

So basically I want my `p` tag to always be displayed under my background image. If I make my window smaller, the `p` tag should not overlap the `background-image`.

I know adding it in the source code as a `img` in a separate div would help a lot, but an answer for this would be nice.

HTML:

```
 <div class="champ-link img-background">
    <a>
      <p>browse the selection</p>
    </a>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```css
.img-background {
     background-image: url(test.jpg);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: 50px 63px; 
}
```

Comment: Can you post an image of what it looks like now, and what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Right now, your <p> is inside the div with the background. You need to get out that tag to allow positioning.

Comment: Try adding `padding-top: 65px`

Comment: Marcos, thanks dude, i was not keen on changing my source code at all , but i understand what you meen and yea was actually a quick fix , thank you. just took the p tag out of the div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.img-background {
   background-image: url(test.jpg);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 50px 63px; 
   padding-top: 63px;
}
```

or

```css
p {
   margin-top: 63px;
}
```

Comment: This is all that you want but responsive. Maybe it works, but is a trick, not a solution. It's better make a good markup instead of changing CSS tricks

Answer (score 1):

Just took the p tag out of the div to allow the p tag positioning.

```
 <div class="champ-link img-background">
 </div>
 <a><p>browse the selection</p></a>
```

css:

```
    img-background {
    background-image: url(test.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 10%;
    background-position: center;
}
```

never overlaps the div.

Comment: i feel like this was the best answer from the lot as Im trying to not use positioning and padding(padding was the sulotion if i did not take the p tag out of div). Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach negating the need for `padding` or `margin` to "make space" for the image size, for instance if you want to scale your image size to your screen size

```
<div class="champ-link">
    <div class='img-background'>
    </div>
    <a><p>browse the selection</p></a>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.img-background {
    background-image: url(test.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%; /* or cover or contain etc. */
    display: block;
    margin:auto; /* can add optional margin for top bottom too 
                    so image doesn't "touch" anchor below it */
    width: 50px; /* or whatever you want/need */
    height:  63px; /* or whatever you want/need */

}
```